# Find distance from center of equilateral triangle to edge in given angle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, angle

I need to find the distance from the barycenter of an equilateral triangle to the edge in a given angle.

Here's a little sketch:

[image: A little sketch]

Given the outer radius of the triangle, the angle and the rotation (assuming the rotation in the picture would be $0$), I need to find the distance from the point on the edge (marked as red in the sketch) to the center.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Where do you count the angle from?

Comment: Counter-clockwise from the right, so 30° would be orthogonal to the right side of the triangle.

Comment: It would be much simpler to count it either from direction to a (certain) vertex or from the direction to the midpoint of a (certain) edge.

Comment: I wouldn't know, really. I don't really have any idea on how to go about this.

Comment: So you start the angle parallel to the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression works for your particular choice of the angle:
$$d=\frac{R}{2\cos(\arccos(\sin(3\alpha))/3)},$$
where $R$ is the radius of circumscribed circle (I assume this was meant by "outer radius of the triangle").

Comment: Thank you so much! Just what I was looking for.

Comment: @DJCoco You're welcome.

Comment: How would you calculate the distance when the triangle is isosceles instead of equilateral?

Comment: @1FpGLLjZSZMx6k What kind of "central" point do you choose for isosceles triangle?

Comment: Let's say the center of gravity

Comment: @1FpGLLjZSZMx6k With this point it will be much more complicated.